# Running .class File in Command Prompt

Tags: javascript, java, class

I'm very new to Java coding and I am trying to run a simple program to print out "Hello World". So I have already created the program using a source code editor (Notepad++) and I saved that as a .java file. After that, I generated my .class file in Command Prompt. The name of the program is "ExampleProgram".

Now that I have my .class file, I'm trying to run it in Command Prompt so my "Hello World" message will be displayed. However, when I type "java ExampleProgram" it displays a message saying "Error: could not find or load main class ExampleProgram".

Extra Info: I'm aware of case-sensitivity, both my ExampleProgram.java and ExampleProgram.class are saved in my documents folder, and I have JBK installed.

```
public class ExampleProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

}

Comment: Show the file structure, the command promt, what you are inputting and where.

Comment: must be class path problem. Try `java -cp . ExampleProgram`

Comment: @Sooplee, are you able to fix your issue ?

Comment: @Raju I'm having a bit of trouble understanding setting my system variables. This is what it currently looks like. http://imgur.com/zgyXEmH I added a PATH thing to my "User variables for Sofia" section with the path for the jdk bin. Was that wrong?

Comment: @Sooplee, instead of adding new user `PATH` variable, update existing system variable `path`. add this path `c:\programs files\java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin`. We can add multiple paths separated by `;`. So, just update like this `c:\programs files\java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin; c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Porgram Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\X86_64` ....etc etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Error: could not find or load main class ExampleProgram"

This error comes if java is not able to locate the class file.

You should specify the location of the class to java program. That can be done by using classpath option

if your *.class is in current directory, use below command.

```
java -cp . ExampleProgram
```

or you can specify absolute path to the class

```
java -classpath "D:/Soople/absolute/path/to/classfile/" ExampleProgram
```

Make sure that your java environment variable is set to jdk bin
for ex: C:\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin

#### Windows 10 and Windows 8

- In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
- Click the Advanced system settings link.
- Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
- In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
- Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

#### Windows 7

- From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
- Choose Properties from the context menu.
- Click the Advanced system settings link.
- Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
- In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
- Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

#### Windows Vista

- From the desktop, right click the My Computer icon.
- Choose Properties from the context menu.
- Click the Advanced tab (Advanced system settings link in Vista).
- Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
- In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
- Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

#### Windows XP

- Select Start, select Control Panel. double click System, and select the Advanced tab.
- Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
- In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
- Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this code (notice the last curly brace that closes the class)

```
public class ExampleProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

then compile/run it:

```
javac ExampleProgram.java
and
java ExampleProgram
```

I highly recommend you get a IDE (maybe for start http://www.bluej.org/ is good for beginners). If you are feeling pro :p go with netbeans or even eclipse).
Good programming.